Pooled sigma as a distance measure between corpora of different sizes
I saw a paper recently published that proposes the use of a RMSD measure to assess the distance between documents. He compared 6 corpora (each stored as a single document) The author shows that the pattern he get using multidimensional scaling is similar (with minor differences) to the patterns he get when using a Cosine for the multidimensional scaling. He propose that software should implement this RMSD metric in addition to the cosine metric when comparing documents (or in his case, corpora).
Does it give us useful information that we don't get with the Cosine? Is this an original contribution to computational linguistics? Is this a meaningful suggestion?

Can you quote the paper you are refering to? Even better, can you spell out the proposed "distance measure" explicitly here?

It is the root mean square distance.  It was applied on 75 categories, and the difference in proportion on each category was squared, then divided by 75.  You can find a description here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation

I still don't see how it becomes something different than cosine distance: As you describe it there are 75 features, each with one value, for all the corpora. Comparing two corpora to determine a distance between them boils down right to cosine distance. What do the authors really do?
